# fuzzy search with elastic search engine using nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following query:

```
router.get('/decisions', (req, res)=>{
let query = {
    index: 'decisions',
    size: 5000,
    body:{
        match:{
            fuzzy:{
                sort: [{ "Date_Lecture": { "order": "asc" } }],
                highlight: {
                    fields: {
                        "paragraph": {
                            "number_of_fragments" : 0 ,
                            "pre_tags": [
                                "<strong><mark>"
                            ],
                            "post_tags": [
                                "</mark></strong>"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                    }
            }
        }
        }
    }

if(req.query.decisions) query.q = `*${req.query.decisions}*`;
client.search(query)
.then(resp => {
    return res.status(200).json({
        decisions: resp
    });
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).json({
        err
    });
});});
```

I am trying to make search with fuzzy search but it gives me an error I don't know maybe its a syntax error or maybe I did not following the correct rule. the error you can see below,

> ResponseError: parsing_exception: [parsing_exception] Reason: Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [match].

can someone please help me to find a way that i can do the search with fuzzy words. Thank you

Comment: Did you try to run the same query against Elasticsearch directly?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to run the same query with Kibana against Elasticsearch and its running fine there in kibana dev tool, but not working with nodejs.

Comment: Could you please try to add `query` between `body:{` and `match:{`: `body: {query: {match: { ... } } }` as shown in the [example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/search_examples.html)

Comment: No it still haveing the same issue.